# Confusion about CVE-2009-0029: Linux Kernel insecure 64 bit system call argument passing

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

Here is the overview of the [CVE-2009-0029](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2009-0029) :

> The ABI in the Linux kernel 2.6.28 and earlier on s390, powerpc, sparc64, and mips 64-bit platforms requires that a 32-bit argument in a 64-bit register was properly sign extended when sent from a user-mode application, but cannot verify this, which allows local users to cause a denial of service (crash) or possibly gain privileges via a crafted system call.

And how can this come accross? Why the flaw does not affect x86_64 or Intel Itanium?

And the Linux Kernel fixs this flaw by replacing the marco define of `__SYSCALL_DEFINEx` below

```
#define __SYSCALL_DEFINEx(x, name, ...)                 \
     asmlinkage long sys##name(__SC_DECL##x(__VA_ARGS__))
```

to

```
#define __SYSCALL_DEFINEx(x, name, ...)                 \
     asmlinkage long sys##name(__SC_DECL##x(__VA_ARGS__));      \
     static inline long SYSC##name(__SC_DECL##x(__VA_ARGS__));  \
     asmlinkage long SyS##name(__SC_LONG##x(__VA_ARGS__))       \
     {                              \
         __SC_TEST##x(__VA_ARGS__);             \
         return (long) SYSC##name(__SC_CAST##x(__VA_ARGS__));   \
     }                              \
     SYSCALL_ALIAS(sys##name, SyS##name);               \
     static inline long SYSC##name(__SC_DECL##x(__VA_ARGS__))
```

I really don't know how can it solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

On these architectures, 32-bit values are handled with 64-bit registers.
So if a function has a 32-bit `int` parameter, a malicious caller could put a value into this register that is larger than would be possible for an `int`.

Furthermore, because the compiler 'knows' that an `int` cannot have a value that would not fit into an `int` variable, it is not easily possible to check if the value is out of range, because the compiler could optimize that check away.

As a workaround, the `SyS_xxx` function first assumes that all its parameters are 64-bit `long` values, and then explicitly converts them to the actual type.

On x86_64 and Itanium, the processor ignores the upper bits of the register when accessing 32-bit values.

Comment: I understand what you said. But I'm sorry you didn't answer my questions. I want to know why cast all the arguments to the long type and then cast to their real type can fix the CVE-2009-0029 vulnerability.